# Error in query : Call to a member function execute()

Tags: 7

My query return me an error.
I have the gid of a organic group.
I want to retrieve the last news for this group.

```
 $query = db_select('node','n');
 $result = $query
 ->fields('n')
 ->condition('type','news','=')
 ->join('field_data_group_audience','fdga','n.nid = fdga.entity_id AND fdga.group_audience_gid = :gid', array(':gid' => $gid))
 ->execute();
```

This query give me a : Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`join()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7) method doesn't return the query object, so can't be used in a chain like you're currently doing. You'll need to do something like this instead:

```
$query = db_select('node','n');
  ->fields('n')
  ->condition('type','news','=');

$query->join('field_data_group_audience','fdga','n.nid = fdga.entity_id AND fdga.group_audience_gid = :gid', array(':gid' => $gid));

$result = $query->execute();
```