# Drupal 7 - eRecruiter profile with Solr Fatal Errors

Tags: views, search

I just installed Drupal 7 using the eRecruiter profile release but I am gettig loads of errors. I know it's not me server as I run 10 other drupal site on my server and there is nothing showing up in the drupal logs.

These are the errors:

This one when I click in Job Search:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function pre_execute() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/public_html/profiles/recruiter/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc on line 2432`

This one when I click on Resume Search:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function pre_execute() on a non-object in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/public_html/profiles/recruiter/modules/views/plugins/views_plugin_display.inc on line 2432`

And this when I click on My Resume:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function entity_i18n_string() in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/public_html/profiles/recruiter/modules/field_collection/field_collection.module on line 913`

I used the exact drupal and module releases that were included with the profile from here:
[http://epiqo.com/recruiter](http://epiqo.com/download/recruiter-7.x-1.0-beta4.tar.gz)

I got the errors... did some searching on line and one person recomended updating Drupal and ALL the mondules. I did all the updates but the errors are still present.

I have installed Apache Solr and it's working fine and drupal says that it has found it.

I then tried to install it localy on my mac and I'm getting the same errors.

My `php_error.log` reported the following:

`[01-May-2012 17:50:28] PHP Fatal error:  Access level to SearchApiViewsHandlerField::$additional_fields must be public (as in class views_handler_field) in /Users/xxx/Sites/vhosts/eRecruiter/profiles/recruiter/modules/search_api/contrib/search_api_views/includes/handler_field.inc on line 195`

and:

I get the same sort of log message when I click on Job search, Resume search and my resume.

Here's a link to the online demo version: http://drupaljobs.epiqo.com/

I'm desperatly needing help with this as I have spent hours search forums and blogs.. got me nowhere :(
Any help will be much appreciated.

C

Answer (score 1):

A lot of errors here, let's see if we can do something..

**Job/Resume Search**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function pre_execute() on a non-object..
```

When you try to invoke the action, the result does not return the query object, and for that reason you have this error, for [example](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28233/error-in-query-call-to-a-member-function-execute).

**php_error.log**

```
PHP Fatal error: Access level to SearchApiViewsHandlerField
```

Changing from protected to Public Field made solve this issue.

**My Resume**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function entity_i18n_string() in
```

Entity 7.x-1.x-dev released on February 28, 2012 - 08:13 [no longer](http://drupal.org/node/1448594#comment-5672624) contains the function entity_i18n_string().

Comment: thanks @Voislav, `Changing from protected to Public Field made solve this issue.` where and how do I do that? This is a profile so I didn't create any of the content types or view.

Comment: Hi @Voislav my last comment may have been missleading.. I havne't fixed this. I was tryin gto quote your line.where and how do I do that? This is a profile so I didn't create any of the content types or view.

Comment: yes I know, but I'm afraid that I do not know how I can help giving you a solution here and also for the [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507256/drupal-7-errors-after-upgrading-from-7-12-to-7-14/10507576#comment13613844_10507576) question., the true is that in fact I'm not a drupal expert. I just try it to help you with my limited knowledge that I learned on my own, I have never worked in industry.. sorry :(